# What did FullSimplify do to deliver a likely wrong expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I recently hit a bug in my code and it eventually turns to be a likely error in the simplification of a formula given by `FullSimplify`. The code is attached and explained below:

[image: FullSimplify[] clearly gives a different expression]

Forget about the complexity in `aa`. The point is `FullSimplify[aa]` is well defined at `λ = 0`. Nonetheless, `FullSimplify[aa*vol]` is singular at `λ = 0`. I could not grasp this because `aa * vol` is nothing but `aa` scaled by a new parameter `vol`. It appears to me that `FullSimplify` does more than just simplification.

For your own verification, the code for `aa` is pasted below:

```
aa = 
  (γ (a4^2 (2 γ + 
          vol λ (1 - 2 ν))^2 (1 + ν) (2 γ + 
          vol λ (1 + ν))^2 + 
       a5^2 (2 γ + 
          vol λ (1 - 2 ν))^2 (1 + ν) (2 γ + 
          vol λ (1 + ν))^2 + 
       a6^2 (2 γ + 
          vol λ (1 - 2 ν))^2 (1 + ν) (2 γ + 
          vol λ (1 + ν))^2 - 
       2 (γ + vol λ (1 + ν))^2 (2 a1 γ + 
          vol λ (a1 - 
             a1 ν + (a2 + a3) ν)) (-2 a1 γ + 
          2 (a2 + a3) γ ν + 
          a1 vol λ (-1 + ν + 2 ν^2)) - 
       2 (γ + vol λ (1 + ν))^2 (2 a2 γ + 
          vol λ (a2 - 
             a2 ν + (a1 + a3) ν)) (-2 a2 γ + 
          2 (a1 + a3) γ ν + 
          a2 vol λ (-1 + ν + 2 ν^2)) - 
       2 (γ + vol λ (1 + ν))^2 (2 a3 γ + 
          vol λ (a3 + (a1 + a2) ν - 
             a3 ν)) (-2 a3 γ + 2 (a1 + a2) γ ν +
           a3 vol λ (-1 + ν + 2 ν^2))))/((2 γ +
        vol λ (1 - 2 ν))^2 (γ + 
       vol λ (1 + ν))^2 (2 γ + 
       vol λ (1 + ν))^2);
```

Comment: `FullSimplify` introduces a term with an explicit `1/\[lambda]` dependence, which causes the problem. This singularity is spurious, though, as `Limit[FullSimplifiy[aa], \[Lambda] -> 0]` gives you a result consistent with setting `\[Lambda]` to zero before the simplification.

Comment: Don't see any problem here since `Series[aa, {\[Lambda], 0, 1}] - 
 Series[FullSimplify[aa], {\[Lambda], 0, 1}]` results in $O\left(\lambda ^2\right)$.

Comment: The limit itself is dubious though because the numerator has a finite value while the denominator vanishes as ```\lambda``` approaches zero. It turns out to be ```1/0``` rather than ```0/0``` or ```inifinity/inifinity```.

Comment: The result of user64494 tells exactly that there EXISTS difference between  original version and FullSimplifed version of the same expression. O(lambda^2) is negligible only when lambda approaches zero, which cannot be generalized to the situations where lambda has a larger value than 1.

Comment: There is no difference, as for example `Together[FullSimplify[aa] - aa]` is zero. In the example of user64494, `Series` is set to cut off at $\mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)$, but that does not mean that the higher powers are necessarily non-zero. For example `Series[aa, {\[Lambda], 0, 20}] - Series[FullSimplify[aa], {\[Lambda], 0, 20}]` is zero up to order $\mathcal{O}(\lambda^{21})$.
Also the other factor in the `1/λ` term vanishes, so it is actually a case of `0/0`